# Layout view not loading in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net, sendgrid, mailgun

So I was investigating how to configure email account verification last night and when I tried running my project today the _Layout view is not loading. The view is still in the Shared folder as is _ViewStart. I do not have any layout declarations in any page.

The frameworks I was playing around its were SendGrid and Mailgun. Based on the information I read I installed Newtonsoft, RestSharp, and SendGrid. I've since removed the using statements and even removed the references to them.

Are there any known conflicts that could cause this to happen?

Comment: Move `_ViewStart` to the `Views` folder not the `Shared` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_ViewStart` should be in the `Views` folder

```
Views
|-> Shared
|   |-> _Shared.cshtml
|
|-> _ViewStart.cshtml
```

Comment: Ugggg. Thanks, Nkosi. Wonder how that got changed.